# Automatic namespace change after moving classes within directory tree in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

When the user adds an item (like class, or interface) to the project in Visual Studio, IDE automatically sets default namespace. Each assembly has default namespace, and in case of sub folders within the project, directory structure is reflected in the namespace.

Following structure

- Project

  - Directory1

    - Subdirectory1

      - Class

produces following namespace:

> namespace Project.Directory1.Subdirectory1

At the beginning everything is clean, and well organized. However later, sometimes we need to move some class to other place. Visual Studio doesn't refactor the namespace after it by default. Is there any option in IDE to turn on? Is there any external tool for it?

Comment: Resharper can definitely do this via Refactor => Move

Comment: @Lennart Thanks, good to know. Maybe I should precise I meant some smaller add-ons, possibly free of charge, because R# is huge solution for such a small problem.

Comment: Considering everything else R# does, it makes for a wise and reasonably priced investment

Comment: This extension just popped up on the VS marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=p2410.NamespaceFixer

Comment: @Lennart This is it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Solution without Resharper or NamespaceFixer:

1. Create new folder named NestedNamespace or whatever you like
2. Move desired classes to new folder
3. Enter `Ctrl + Shift + H`
4. Under `Look in` section click three dot button ("Choose search folders")
5. Add new folder
6. Under `Find what` section enter `namespace MasterNamespace`
7. Under `Replace with` section enter `namespace MasterNamespace.NestedNamespace`
8. Click `Replace All`
9. (Optional) Remove duplicates by replacing `MasterNamespace.NestedNamespace.NestedNamespace` => `MasterNamespace.NestedNamespace`

By this way you need to update manually all references outside NestedNamespace, usually by error log.

This is "raw" method, but quite fast and does not require any external programs/add-ons.