# How to use a "flat" namespace in whole C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

I want to use the same namespace for my whole c# class library. But the default behavior for new files is to use a namespace like `[Base namespace].[Folder 1].[Folder 2]`.

Is there a simple way or plugin for visual studio 2019 to make all new files use the same namespace? So just `[Base namespace]` whatever the folder?

But just for a single project, I don't want to change the global file templates.

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: Obviously, you could just use no folders within the project. (Conversely, if you need to use the folders to manage complexity, why do you need it in the source but *not* need it in the namespace?)

Comment: As others already stated, you should stick to the common naming rules that define those namespaces, which normally automatically reflects your project's structure.

If for some reason you only want to use a simple namespace, for example a generic nuget package to reuse in your projects, then you could simply find-and-replace it inside your project, or use resharper. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302567/how-to-change-namespace-of-entire-project/8302755

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Project Namespace in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871314/change-project-namespace-in-visual-studio) and [Change Default Namespace when creating Class in Folder (Visual Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317901/change-default-namespace-when-creating-class-in-folder-visual-studio) and [Automatic namespace change after moving classes within directory tree in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934548/automatic-namespace-change-after-moving-classes-within-directory-tree-in-visual)

Comment: @zaitsman I think the tag "visual-studio" makes it quite clear it's about visual studio ;-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No folders is definetly not a good solution. I have also actived "show types from not imported namespaces", because mostly I really don't care about namespaces except for the base one.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Nope this is not what I was asking about, sorry.

Comment: If you happen to use ReSharper, you can set the "Namespace Provider" property of the folder to False.

Comment: @KithorasCarzyl no it doesn't because you may be using VS 2012 for example or VS code. Anyways, in VS 2019 create yourself a vsix with custom item template like so: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-custom-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround I'm pleased with:

I installed this nice extension [Visual Studio Namespace Fixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=p2410.NamespaceFixer). It allows you to define a template for your namespaces and then can apply it to all .cs, .xaml, and other files in your project.

Under `Options -> Namespace Fixer options -> Use default project namespace` I defined the format `{projectRootNamespace}` for `Namespace format`.

Not I just have to select my files and folders in the projects base folder (in Visual Studio, not in the windows explorer), rightclick and select `Adjust namespaces` and all files in all subfolders will change their namespace to the projects root namespace :-)

Awesome if you create and use a lot of class and other files in your NuGet lib.